# How to implement my specific algorithm on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

I have a dataframe:

```
 id     value1   value2
"a1"     20       25
"a1"     20       37
"a1"     36       25
"b1"     40       63
"b1"     40       42
"b1"     60       42
"b1"     60       63
```

For each group of "id" I want to compare each unique value in column "value1" with each unique value in column "value2" from same group. The comparison is just difference of numbers between value2 and value1. If difference is >= than 2 than in new column "is_differ" must be 0 and if lower than it must be 1. So desired result is:

```
 id     value1   is_differ
"a1"     20       1
"a1"     36       0
"b1"     40       1
"b1"     60       1
```

for "a1" 36 is_deffier is 0 because 25-36<2, 37-36<2.

How to do that?

More detailed explanation:

The algorithm should work like this:

for each group grouped by "id" we take each unique value in column "value1" and calculating difference between each value in column "value2" and it. For example for "id" "a1" for value1 20 we calculate 25-20=5,37-20=17; for value1 36: 25-36=-11,237-36=1. In new dataframe:

```
 id     value1   is_differ
"a1"     20       1
"a1"     36       0
"b1"     40       1
"b1"     60       1
```

is_differ is 1 if at least one of differences was higher than 2 (>=2). In case of id: "a1" value1: 36 there wasn't any case when difference was >=2 (25-36=-11,237-36=1)

Comment: probably some combination of `groupby` and `count` or some such

Comment: the condition is quite unclear, what does "*25-36<2, 37-36<2*" mean?

Comment: @mozway it means that difference between all value2 and value1 for "a1" 36 are lower than 2

Comment: @mozway `25-36` is `-11`. `-11 < 2` is true.

Comment: @Barmar yeah and that's why it is 0, if it was higher than 2 than it is 1 in column is_differ

Comment: you mean you get the diff of all value2 and the max of value1?

Comment: no not max, but each value from value1 is compared with each value in value2

Comment: What if it's `>=2` for some values, and `<2` for other values?

Comment: @in that case it is 1 (one time >=2 is enough)

Comment: I still don't grasp the logic, you should really break down all the numbers. Why don't you compare to `20` in the group a1?

Comment: @mozway ill break it down in details in few minutes

Comment: @mozway i added more detailed explanation

Comment: @Barmar I added more detailed explanation

Comment: I hope I understood, give it a try

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use two `groupby`, one to get the max value2 per id and compute the difference to each value1, and another to aggregate per id/value1:

```
(df
 .assign(is_differ=df.groupby('id')['value2']
                     .transform('max')
                     .sub(df['value1'])
                     .gt(2).astype(int))
 .groupby(['id', 'value1'], as_index=False).agg({'is_differ': 'max'})
)
```

output:

```
     id  value1  is_differ
0  "a1"      20          1
1  "a1"      36          0
2  "b1"      40          1
3  "b1"      60          1
```